# Priority 8-to-3 encoder in Verilog (case, casex)

Tags: authentication, switch-statement, bit-manipulation, verilog, system-verilog

I'm trying to describe a SN54LS348 element (8-line to 3-line priority encoder).
The truth table is:

```
          INPUTS            OUTPUTS   
E | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ** A2 A1 A0 | GS EO
///////////////////////////////////////
H | X X X X X X X X ** Z  Z  Z  | H  H
L | H H H H H H H H ** Z  Z  Z  | H  L
L | X X X X X X X L ** L  L  L  | L  H
L | X X X X X X L H ** L  L  H  | L  H
L | X X X X X L H H ** L  H  L  | L  H
L | X X X X L H H H ** L  H  H  | L  H
L | X X X L H H H H ** H  L  L  | L  H
L | X X L H H H H H ** H  L  H  | L  H
L | X L H H H H H H ** H  H  L  | L  H
L | L H H H H H H H ** H  H  H  | L  H
```

Here's my implementation:

```
module L348 (E, D0, D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7, A0, A1, A2, GS, EO);

input E, D0, D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7;
output A0, A1, A2, GS, EO;

assign D = {D0, D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7};

parameter HIGH_IMPEDANCE = 3'bz;

reg [7:0] MASK_1 = 8'b0000_0001;
reg [7:0] MASK_2 = 8'b0000_0011;
reg [7:0] MASK_3 = 8'b0000_0111;
reg [7:0] MASK_4 = 8'b0000_1111;
reg [7:0] MASK_5 = 8'b0001_1111;
reg [7:0] MASK_6 = 8'b0011_1111;
reg [7:0] MASK_7 = 8'b0111_1111;
reg [7:0] MASK_8 = 8'b1111_1111;

reg [2:0] A;
reg [1:0] GS_EO;
reg [7:0] temp;

reg [7:0] mem [7:0];

initial
begin
mem[0] = MASK_1;
mem[1] = MASK_2;
mem[2] = MASK_3;
mem[3] = MASK_4;
mem[4] = MASK_5;
mem[5] = MASK_6;
mem[6] = MASK_7;
mem[7] = MASK_8;
temp = 8'bxxxx_xxxx;
end

assign {A2, A1, A0} = A;
assign {GS, EO} = GS_EO;

integer i;

always @(*)
begin
for (i = 7; i > 0; i = i - 1)
    if (mem[i] & D == mem[i])
        begin
        temp = mem[i];
        i = -1;
        end
if (E)
    begin
    A = HIGH_IMPEDANCE;
    GS_EO = 2'b11;
    end
else
    begin
        if (temp == 8'b1111_1111)
            begin
            A = HIGH_IMPEDANCE;
            GS_EO = 2'b10;
            end
        else
            begin

            GS_EO = 2'b01;
            case (temp)
                8'b0000_0001: A = 3'b001;
                8'b0000_0011: A = 3'b010;
                8'b0000_0111: A = 3'b011;
                8'b0000_1111: A = 3'b100;
                8'b0001_1111: A = 3'b101;
                8'b0011_1111: A = 3'b110;
                8'b0111_1111: A = 3'b111;
            endcase

            end
    end
end
endmodule
```

It fails to achieve the switching of signals A2-A0 which are always in a X-state (except when E = H). I've tried many solutions, but it feels like simulator can't manage 'case' block ( I tried also 'casex' block). There is a bug somewhere, but I can't figure it out. Does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got quite a few things going on here but your most immediate problem is probably.

```
assign D = {D0, D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7};
```

This implicitly defined wire is only going to be 1 bit wide and so the high 7b are going to be dropped.  Isn't Verilog fun?

There are other logical problems but the easiest way of doing a priority encoder with a case statement is as follows:

```
casez (in)
  4'b???1 : out = 0;
  4'b??10 : out = 1;
  4'b?100 : out = 2;
  4'b1000 : out = 3;
  default : out = 0; //no match
endcase
```

The `casez` allow you to put in `?` for don't care conditions similar to your truth table.  The first matching entry is taken which give you the priority behavior. 
 Adapt as needed for your case for width, direction of priority, width of IO, etc...

Finally as a stylistic concern your early loop termination should use `break` rather than directly modifying the loop variable.

Comment: Hmmm, I've read that using of 'break' expression in Verilog is very poor style of programming.

Comment: It can be.  In behavioral code I would definitely chose 'break'.  I'm actually not sure that either style is synthesizable .  The usual way to handle this in RTL would be to code the loop such that it always runs through all value of 'i' but that the last successful match would be the one you want.

Comment: Yeah, the main problem with the code above was 'D' net with 1-bit word length. Thank you for your reply!